# executing macros on time interval in ms-project

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, ms-project

I'm trying to create a macro to save an ms-project file in a specific format to a given location at a set interval while the application is open. I've got it mostly working, except the executing on an interval part.

I've had a bit of a google around and when using excel or word you can use the Application.OnTime method & a time offset to call a sub at the required interval. Unfortunately it doesn't look like this method exists in MS-Project.

Is there an alternative method I can use here or should I abandon this idea?

Comment: Cant you use some kind of event? I assume you only want to save the file after a certain action has occurred

Comment: Well, the idea was to save the file on a (somewhat) regular basis so it could be used as a datasource for another application - it's a large project file that's usually open all day & edited at somewhat irregular intervals. Given the save operation is pretty intensive if it's tied to an event then it'd need to be something that's unlikely to be triggered frequently. I don't know enough about vba/project to know where to start. I've given up on the idea at this point anyway - but thanks for your reply.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn254092.aspx have your pick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this is a late answer, but I have a solution I used for a similar problem. Just jump on the Project_Change event since it runs frequently, and compare against a variable.

```
Public lastSave As Date


Private Sub Project_Change(ByVal pj As Project)


    If DateDiff("n", lastSave, Now()) > 1 Then ' Replace 1 with # of minutes between saves.
        Application.FileSave
        lastSave = Now()

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That does indeed look like it'd fit the bill. I've well and truly moved on to other ideas at this point, but thankyou!